# When to use NULL and when to use '\0' in linked list in C?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I learned that in C: `null char == '\0' == NULL`, and I wrote a loop below to read from the start to the end of a char[] in C.

```
// case #1
char buf[32];
while (buf[i] != NULL){
    //do something...
}
```

However, my gcc compiler gave me a warning: comparison between pointer and integer. Someone mentioned that I was confusing two separate concepts: NULL is for pointers, whereas '\0' is for characters.  So to get rid of the warning, I should use '\0' since my loop tests a char.

Now I am writing a linked list, and testing if a head pointer points to a node or not.  Since it's struct, it's reasonable to use `if (h1 == NULL)` but apparently the compiler also compiles when I use `if (h1 == '\0')` even though the node is a struct but not a char. Can someone give some help why both '\0' and NULL can be used in this case while they can't be both use on the first case?

```
// case #2
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};
```

Comment: Use `\0` in strings for the terminator, where required. Use NULL for a pointer that doesn't point to anything (for example, the end of a linked list. They are not the same, even if they can be interchanged in some circumstances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very common confusion.  A "null character" (often spelled NUL, with only one L, for historical reasons) is a *character* that compares equal to zero.  A "null pointer" is a *pointer* that compares equal to zero.  The difference is only the type -- but that is an important difference.  The compiler is allowed, but not required, to object to your program, because you are comparing a *character* value to a null *pointer* constant.

C has a fairly loose type system, especially when it comes to integer constants, so you can *get away with* using constants with a formally incorrect type a lot of the time.  This is especially true when it comes to zero: the integer literal `0` can be used everywhere it is safe to use the macro `NULL` or the character literal `'\0'`.  In fact, the implementation is specifically allowed to use `#define NULL 0` in all editions of the C standard.  Because of this, there are a small handful of contexts where one absolutely must use `(T*)0` for some concrete type T, *instead of* either bare `0` or `NULL`, such as when passing null pointers to a function that takes a variable number of arguments (e.g. `execl`).

As further icing on the confusion cake, in C character literals have type `int`, not `char`, and `'\0'` is a legitimate *null pointer constant*.  (In C++ neither of those things is true.)

Best practice in C, IMNSHO, is to use `'\0'` for the null *character*, and `0` — *not* `NULL` — for the null *pointer*.

Comment: Even better would be to use the term "NULL" to refer to a pointer and "nul" for a character, as in the typical ASCII table. Also I understand that `NULL` is not necessarily `0` (in MPU) so better to use the defined value `NULL`. And note that `0` and `'\0'` are syntactically equivalent: both are of type `int` and both have the value 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane In C, in my not so humble opinion, NULL is just another name for the integer constant `0` and it's almost always better to use `0`.  In particular, people may be confused into thinking that they _don't_ need to cast NULL in e.g. the argument list of `execl`, when in fact they do.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know what you mean by "in MPU NULL is not necessarily 0" but in C, null pointers always compare equal to zero, *even if* the bit representation of a null pointer isn't all-bits-zero.

Comment: That is what I was trying to say: `0` may be a valid address it is taken care of if `NULL` is used.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's not, though.  `NULL` is just a macro, and it's required to expand to an integer literal _with the value zero_.  Conversely, _any_ integer constant expression whose value is zero converts to a null pointer when converted to pointer type. In other words, the C standard flat-out forbids zero to be a valid address.

Comment: To your first comment - and in your question, why is `NULL` defined at all? This seems to reduce to opinion.

Comment: And `0` **can be** a valid address in MPU systems, which is why `NULL` should be used and not `0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane you're very incorrect. `NULL` is always equal to 0 in C (i.e. `NULL == 0` is always true); NULL, 0 and `'\0'` are all null pointer constants; However the *bit-pattern that is used to represent a null pointer need not be 0*.

Comment: That is because `0` may be a valid address. Otherwise, why is `NULL` implementation defined?

Comment: It is implementation-defined whether it is defined as `0` or `0L` or `(void*)0` or...

Comment: C places no restrictions or demands on the hardware used to implement it. That is why `NULL` may not have all bits 0, even if it *compares* to `0`.

Comment: @zwol can you please cite for me "the C standard flat-out forbids zero to be a valid address".

Comment: @WeatherVane [N1570 section 6.3.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3) paragraph 3: "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function."

Comment: @WeatherVane It is technically true that the _bit representation_ of a null pointer is not required to be the same as the bit representation of `(uintptr_t)0`, but the only way a strictly conforming program can tell is by using `memcmp`. The implementation-defined conversion between integers and pointers (6.3.2.3p5,6) is effectively required to preserve the equivalence between null pointers and integer zero, because the compiler can't always prove that a zero didn't came from an integer constant expression.

Comment: @WeatherVane The allowance for the bit representation of a null pointer to not be the same as the bit representation of an integer zero is _meant_ to cover your MPU systems (I think; I'm not familiar with that acronym) but I suspect in practice it doesn't work out, and you would need to remap the address space to leave the first page or so of linear addresses reserved.

Comment: @zwol thank you, it's still rather muddy to me. I thought that the internally non-0 representation was meant to allow for where `0` is a valid address, but the compiler would hide the implementation details. I have never used a `NULL` pointer in embedded software (apart from where it is used as a flag returned by functions) because I always pre-allocate memory requirements so that `malloc` is never used.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the compiler, `NULL` may be defined may different ways:

```
#define NULL ((char *)0)
```

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

```
#define NULL 0L
```

```
#define NULL 0
```

`NULL` is meant for pointer comparisons.  However, integer `0` is a special case that is allowed for pointer comparisons, which is why you can compare a `ListNode*` pointer against `0` directly (otherwise the above `NULL` defines where a pointer type-cast is not present would not work):

```
if (h1 == 0)
```

Or simpler:

```
if (!h1)
```

A `'\0'` character literal is an `int` in C, and is implicitly convertible to an `int` in C++.  So `'\0'` can be used in pointer comparisons as well.

You should use `'\0'` (or just `0`) for character comparisons, do not use `NULL`:

```
while (buf[i] != '\0') // or 0
```

Or simpler:

```
while (buf[i])
```

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but there is no implicit char-to-int conversion in `'\0'`.  Character constants have type `int` in C, unlike C++ where they have type `char`.  In practice, there is no type nor value difference between `'\0'` and `0` in C, but I completely agree with you that readability is greatly enhanced if one is used when dealing with characters and the other when dealing with numeric values.  Similarly, `NULL` should be used for pointers, even though `0` would be correct but less readable.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is effectively used as null terminator for linked lists or arrays of pointers. `'\0'` is used as a null terminator for strings (i.e. char arrays)

If you had an array of structs, you might want to loop over them until you reach the end:

```
MyStruct** things = ...
for(int i = 0; things[i] != NULL; i++) {
    // Do something with things[i]
}
```

This loop will end when the pointer to the last struct is `NULL`.